# Undefined \pgfsetpath: is tikz or Miktex update responsible

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, miktex, updating

I run the following simple example using `MikTeX` 2.9 (complete installation) that is regularly updated (this is one of the first examples in TikZ manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path [name path=onek, draw] (2,0) -- (2,4);
 \path [name path=twok, draw] (0,0) -- +(30:4);
\draw [name intersections={of=onek and twok, by=x}]
[very thick,red] (2,0) -- (x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and get the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \pgfsetpath 

l.44 ...me intersections={of=onek and twok, by=x}]

?
```

Here is the result of `\listfile`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2008/02/13 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.27)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2008/02/20 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.21)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2008/01/15 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.6)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2008/02/07 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.31)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/01/23  (rcs-revision 1.6)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2007/11/07 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.8)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
```

I guess some of my PGF files must out-dated, and I am puzzled why my frequent updates using MikTeX update tool have not worked.

Comment: It seems you have an outdated version of TikZ somewhere. Can you look in the log file and show the path of `tikz.sty`?

Comment: You could use the `--recorder` option and check the generated `.fls` file. It includes the absolute paths of all packages.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Very interesting feature!

Comment: works fine for me- I think [an update is in order](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)